# Detect keyboard language change in a Windows Store App?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is there any way to detect keyboard language changes in a Windows Store App? Other than polling using Windows.Globalization.Language.currentInputMethodLanguageTag of course...

On Desktop it to listen for WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE, but... well it's only for desktop...

Thanks,
Hani

Comment: Are you sure, that it's C++ question ? Why did you add C++ tag ?

Comment: well, yes, I want the code in C++, because basically on Windows 8 there are more things implemented in native than in managed